# PHP Look behind Regex with variable distance

Tags: php, regex

I need to match a sequence of characters but only if it's not preceded by a "?" or "#" with 0 or more (any) number of wildcard characters in between.

```
$extension_regex = 
'/
    (?<!\?|\#)    # Negative look behind not "?" or "#"
    \/            # Match forward slash
    [^\/\?#]+     # Has one or more of any character except forward slash, question mark and hash
    \.            # Dot
    ([^\/\?#]+)   # Has one or more of any character except forward slash, question mark and hash
/iux';
```

Examples:

"?randomcharacters/index.php" should not get matched

"#randomcharacters/index.php" should not get matched

"randomcharacters/index.php" should get matched

I understand that the lookbehind is not working because it sees that "/index.php" is not preceded by ? or #. But I can't figure out how to add wildcard "distance" between the ? or # and the /index.php.

#### The Answer

Based on @Jerry's answer. Here's the full regex as the answer:

```
$extension_regex = 
'~
    ^
    (?:
        (?!
           [?#]
           .*
           /
           [^/?#]+
           \.
           [^/?#]+
        )
        .
    )*
    /
    [^/?#]+
    \.
    ([^/?#]+)
~iux';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot put a variable width assertion within a lookbehind in PCRE, but you could perhaps use a work around using a negative lookahead, something like this maybe?

```
^(?:(?![#?].*/index.php).)*(/index.php)
```

I added the capture group just to get the part you want to match, even though it might not be actually useful here.

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/yW6vC4)

`^(?:(?![#?].*/index.php).)*` will basically match any character, as long as there's no `#` or `?` followed by the string you want to match (`/index.php`) immediately ahead.

In C#, you might otherwise be able to use:

```
(?<![#?].*)/index.php
```

Comment: I adapted your code to be a bit more flexible. Not just index.php. It works now: http://regex101.com/r/pZ0jL0

Comment: @CMCDragonkai Of course that's okay :) Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

This may help:

```
$extension_regex = 'string';
$arr = array('?', '#', '0');//these are the forbidden characters
if(in_array(substr($extension_regex, 0, 1), $arr))
    echo "true";
else
    echo "false";
```